How to redirect a specific path from a remote URL to a local directory on Mac?
I am changing images and CSS on a Mac for a remote website that already exists. Let's pretend the remote website is:

https://billybobsoysters.com

I'd like to open that website in my Chrome browser at that correct domain, and see the actual website, but I'd like all images and CSS to load from my local directories.
So this path would go to the actual remote website, like it would for everyone else:

https://billybobsoysters.com/menu/index.php

But all these paths would point (for me alone) to a directory at Users/myusername/Documents/billybobsoysters/css/ (and to the files in it) on my own Mac:

https://billybobsoysters.com/css/
https://billybobsoysters.com/css/default.css
https://billybobsoysters.com/css/subdir/supercool.css

Likewise, these paths would point to a directory locally as well:

https://billybobsoysters.com/img/
https://billybobsoysters.com/img/giantpic.jpg
https://billybobsoysters.com/img/newfolder/banner.png

But every path that isn't /img/ or /css/ would point to the actual website.
Is this possible? How would I accomplish it?
Please give as detailed instructions as possible. This is all new to me.
Thanks in advance!
